# How did 'cocodrilo' originate from 'crocodile'?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, cross-linguistic, spanish, metathesis

The English word **crocodile** seems to originate from the Latin **crocodīlus** and Ancient Greek **κροκόδιλος**. Indeed it has ended up very similar in several modern languages: German (Krokodile), Russian (крокодил), Hungarian (krokodilfélék).

But does anyone know why the Spanish (and only they) moved the r and call it a **cocodrilo**?

Comment: Oh, that's funny, I didn't know. I have no idea how this metathesis came about (God, I hope it is really metathesis this time).

Comment: It is definitely metathesis. Incidentally, the recursive mnemonic for _metathesis_ is _methatesis_; you can probly guess what _haplogy, epenethesis, pocopy, syncpy,_ and _athemtic_ are.

Comment: see also http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cocodrilo

Comment: @jlawler: Haha, yes, although your *pocopy* and *syncpy* are also examples of the phenomenon called *polyphonee* (sic).

Comment: Note that *Cocodrillus* [also existst in laitn](http://latin-dictionary.net/definition/10667/cocodrillus-cocodrilli). But this merely shifts the question to Latin...

Comment: Side note on `Krokodile`: This is German plural; singular is `Krokodil`

Answer (score 13):

This is an example of metathesis, the rearranging of sounds or syllables in a word. It occurred in a number of words in the evolution from Latin to Spanish:

- `Latin` [*pa**r**abo**l**a*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parabola#Latin) > `Old Spanish` *pa**r**ab**l**a* > `Spanish` [*pa**l**ab**r**a*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palabra#Spanish) 'word'
- `Latin` [*mī**r**ācu**l**um*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/miraculum#Latin) > `Old Spanish` *mi**r**ác**l**o* > *mi**r**ag**l**o* > `Spanish` [*mi**l**ag**r**o*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/milagro#Spanish) 'miracle'
- `Latin` [*pe**r**icŭ**l**um*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/periculum#Latin) > `Old Spanish` *pe**r**ico**l**o* > *pe**r**ig**l**o* > `Spanish` [*pe**l**ig**r**o*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peligro#Spanish) 'danger, peril'
- `Latin` [*c**r**ocodīlus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crocodilus#Latin) > `Old Spanish` *c**r**ocodilo* > `Spanish` [*cocod**r**ilo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cocodrilo#Spanish) 'crocodile'
- *a**n**ima**l**ia* > *a**l**ima**ñ**a*
- *int**egr**are* > *ent**reg**ar*
- *vi**dŭ**us/a* > *vi**ud**o/a*
- *crusta* > *c**rost**a* > *c**ostr**a*
- *A**l**ge**r**ia* > *A**r**ge**l**ia*
- *guir**l**a**n**da*  > *guir**n**a**l**da*
- `Old Spanish` *mur* + *ciego*> `Old Spanish` *murciégo* > (diminutive) *murcié**g**a**l**o* > *murcié**l**a**g**o*

There are even instances of this happening multiple times to recreate the original syllabic pattern:

- *p**rae**lātus* > *p**re**lado* > *p**er**lado* > *p**re**lado*

This also occurs commonly with these non-standard (i.e. not recognised by the *RAE*) pronunciations (and associated spellings):

- [*c**roqu**eta*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dent%C3%ADfrico#Spanish) > *c**ocr**eta*
- [*dent**ífr**ico*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dent%C3%ADfrico#Spanish) > *dent**ríf**ico*
- [*calc**o**m**a**nía*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calcoman%C3%ADa#Spanish) > *calc**a**m**o**nía*
- *ve**r**e**d**a* > *ve**d**e**r**a*
- *ce**r**ebro* > *ce**l**ebro*
- *gui**j**a**rr**o* > *gui**rr**a**j**o*
- *p**rogr**ama* > *p**ogr**ama*
- *nea**n**de**r**tal* > *nea**r**de**n**tal*
- ***c***ol**ch**oneta > ***ch***ol**c**oneta
- *met**eoro**logía* > *met**ereo**logía*

---

<sub>**Note:** These changes do not occur in all Romance languages, see:</sub>

- <sub>`French` *Algérie*</sub>
- <sub>`French` *miracle*, `Italian` *miracolo*</sub>
- <sub>`French` *guirlande*, `Italian` *ghirlanda*</sub>
- <sub>`Portuguese` *crocodilo*, `Galician` *crocodilo*</sub>
- <sub>`Portuguese` *perigo*, `Galician` *perigo*, `Italian` *pericolo*</sub>

<sub>But other Romance languages **did** in fact undergo the same change as Spanish with this last word:</sub>

- <sub>`Italian` *coccodrillo*</sub>
- <sub>`Sicilian` *cuccudrillu*</sub>
- <sub>`Vernazzese (Spezzino (Ligurian))` [*cuccudrìllu*](http://www.dialettu.it/parola.php?voce=cuccudrillu1746)</sub>
- <sub>`Logudorese Sardinian` [*cuccudrillu*](http://vocabolariocasu.isresardegna.it/definizione.php?codice=l3871300)</sub>
- <sub>`Corsican` [*cuccudrillu*](https://co.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idra_di_Lerna#In_u_medievu)</sub>
- <sub>`Asturian` *cocodrilu*</sub>
- <sub>`Old French` *cocodril*</sub>
- <sub>`Picard` *cocodril*</sub>
- <sub>`Catalan` *cocodril*</sub>
- <sub>`Languedocien (Occitan)` *cocodril*</sub>

---

<sub>Sources:</sub>

<sub>• https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metathesis_(linguistics)#Spanish</sub>
<sub>• [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metátesis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Met%C3%A1tesis)</sub>
<sub>• https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crocodile#French</sub>

Comment: It's interesting that modern French then reverted back to the form closer to Latin.

Comment: Yeah, this wasn't a 'natural' shift in sounds but a conscious attempt in the 16th century to use a form closer to the 'original' Latin/Greek forms.

http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/crocodile

Comment: From many of your examples, it would seem that it was common for an /r/ to move away from the stressed syllable: peligro instead of perigo, milagro instead of miraclo, palabra instead of parabla, entregar instead of integrar. Evidently, the opposite happened to cocodrillo, where the /r/ moved to the stressed syllable.

Comment: _"l"_ and _"r"_ were frequently swapped in all possible configurations in the evolution Spanish words (examples of *dissimilation*): A**R**BO**R**, P**R**ECA**R**IA, **L**OCA**L**IS, co**l**one**ll**o, **L**IQUI**R**ITIA  →  á**r**bo**l**, p**l**ega**r**ia, **l**uga**r**, co**r**one**l**, **r**ega**l**iz

Comment: @apat : Interestingly, this word is known to be hard to master for small French kids. They often say «cocrodile», and it is a stereotypical «cute» example of childspeak. I guess it hints at the somehow non-natural position of r in crocodile in French

Answer (score 11):

Actually the word `crocodilo` is listed in some Spanish dictionaries, but one thing is what dictionaries say and another thing is what real users of language do. Anyway, it seems that this is a case of **metathesis**, which is a process that reorders the segments of a given string. Thus, perhaps `crocodilo` became `cocodrilo` after the /r/ was reordered in the word. In Italian it is very similar: `coccodrillo`, so Spanish is not the only case as you think. This phenomenon could have started in Latin for `crocodilus`, and this would explain that Spanish and Italian exhibit the metathesis too.

Comment: i can confirm that in croatian langage this happens often with little children cannot say: krokodil; but they say: kokrodil. ;) it is considered a slip of the tongue here, as it happens with adults as well.

Comment: It's very hard for me as an English speaker to put the 'r' anywhere other than in the first syllable.

Comment: For now, you've not actually answered the question; you've only described the phenomenon in linguistic terms. *Why* was there metathesis?

Comment: _Why_ questions in linguistics are usually unanswerable. We can often answer the _how_, and sometimes a question like _why should this have happened at this time and place rather than anywhere else_; but usually we cannot predict that a certain change will or will not happen, or explain why it did or didn't.

Comment: As by Hume, all "why" questions are fundamentally without answer, but still, science is full of attempts to make causal explanations. As an example, a typical phonological answer will often refer to a sound pattern that becomes suboptimal in a diachronic context as triggering change, such as violations of the sonority hierarchy (e.g. when a word is introduced from a  language with a different hierarchy and becomes regularised).
Either way, I do not see how the fact that "why" questions are supposedly unanswerable somehow makes mentioning the name of a phenomenon a satisfactory *explanation*.

Answer (score 1):

I think that one should think of the Vulgar Latin that was spoken in many countries by speakers  who were not too firm in Latin or Vulgar Latin. And such  special cases of metathesis that *r* not only jumps from its place before a vowel after it but also to a place in the last part of a long word occur, because a lot of speakers could not reproduce long words correctly. That's how I would explain such curiosities that *r* is shifted to a remote position.

Answer (score -3):

I think that with time the original word of *crocodīlus* has become *cocodrilo* in Español, through laziness or just by error. The same thing happens with *Jerusalem* (יְרוּשָׁלַיִם (*yerushaláyim*) in Hebrew): in Spanish it is called *Jerusalén* (with a final *-n*). On many occasions I have heard people say *"Ansterdan"* (with two *n*'s). Horrible but true.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics SE. Do you happen to know of any Spanish etymological dictionaries that you could use to back up your claim? On this SE we're more interested in answers backed up by external sources or examples. Your current answer seems a bit too much like a guess. Maybe this would be better as a comment.

Comment: -1 does not answer the question, does not cite sources