# How does Metathesis work?

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, romance-languages, spanish, metathesis

How does it happen? What motivated latin "parabola" to change into Spanish "palabra" and why does english "ask" is often changed to "aks"?

Comment: Why is the sound changes in palabra analysed as metathesis? It is simpler to consider a lambdacism + a rhotacism.

Comment: @amegnunsen Could you explain why that's simpler?

Comment: @tobiornottobi Because the cost is less high. Rhotacism and lambdacism are sound changes already present in Romance languages. Dissimilation r/l in Latin is well known. Moreover, It is more usual to see metathesis between adjacent sounds, here r and l are not side by side. It is just a thought, nothing certain.

Comment: And why would semper change to sempre in portuguese or super change to sobre?

Comment: @amegnunsen are there lambdacisms and rhotacisms in Spanish *in the same environments* as here? If not, then metathesis may be a less costy explanation.

Comment: Resonants that can be syllabic, like r, l, n, etc. often shift position with their vocalic parts, so that _-er-_ and _-re-_, for instance, are common variations with no particular significance. When you have two of them, like l and r, they can do all kinds of tricks. Consider the Spanish and English spellings of _colonel_, for instance, and their respective pronunciations. Or consider _marble_ and Lat _marmora_, or just the ordinary morphology of the [Latin adjective ending _-alis_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/pdf-files/Latin_dissimilation.pdf).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a partial answer.

I think metathesis is often explained in terms of perceptual similarities between the variants. Additionally, sometimes we can say that one form has a "preferred" phonotactic structure. But in general, metathesis is known to be a difficult thing to explain in terms of linguistic theory.

The Spanish case is complicated because Romance languages are known to have processes of lambdacism/rhotacism that aren't metathesis-based (as amegnunsen mentioned in a comment; although I don't know of any specific Latin-to-Spanish sound laws that would be relevant here), and also processes of liquid dissimilation ("pelegrino" is attested as a variant form of *peregrino,* from Latin *peregrīnus*). So at first glance, it isn't entirely obvious that *palabra* is best analyzed as a case of long-distance metathesis. It's probably necessary to look carefully at the details of how this word and similar words developed in Spanish to determine whether it is a true case of metathesis (and if so, why/how the consonants metathesized). Unfortunately, I have not done this, so I can't say anything certain about the situation here. Ukemi's answer to [How did 'cocodrilo' originate from 'crocodile'?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/26564/5581) gives other examples of liquid metathesis in Spanish (and also of other changes).

Changes between **sk** and **ks** have been somewhat common in the history of English, and can also be seen in Romance in various words, but I don't know what explanation would account for the presence of metathesis in the word *ask.* As mentioned in the Language Log post "[Leaf-blower metathesis?](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2734)", we see *-ks* variants in Old English, at a stage where the consonant cluster was intervocalic (as far as I can tell, in all forms of the word). In some languages, such as Faroese and apparently also Lithuanian, we see a process of metathesis of -sk- to -ks- before certain consonants that are added by inflection (the details differ between the languages; see "[Metathesis: Formal and Functional Considerations](http://roa.rutgers.edu/files/492-0202/492-0202-HUME-0-0.PDF)", Hume 2001, for descriptions), but that doesn't seem relevant in the case of English *ask*; I don't know of any dialect of English that has a paradigm like /ask, asks, akst/. English speakers may show cluster simplification of the three-consonant word-final sequences /sks/, /skt/ or /kst/, but I don't think that's very similar to what we see in Lithuanian or Faroese.

Changes between **sp** and **ps** are also known to occur; e.g. in the word for *wasp.*

If we analyze the *ask~aks* variation as a example of synchronic metathesis in English, it's probably related in some way to the position of the -sk sequence in the coda of the syllable in the plain form *ask.* I don't think that any appreciable amount of English speakers produce /ks/ instead of /sk/ at the start of words. The only other example of /sk/~/ks/ variation at the end of a word that I can think of is *asterisk,* which has a (fairly stigmatized) variant pronunciation ending in /ks/.

Answer (score 2):

As a sound change, there are very many ways for it to happen. In the case of "ask", the cause is lost in history. The OED indicates that forms like *achsian, acsian* are attested in Old English, and in Middle English gained popularity in the south and the midlands, but was considered vulgar. But this isn't a regular sound change, and in current English this example stands alone. Metathesis as a sporadic process in child language acquisition has been observed in Japanese; lateral metathesis presumably is related to the "localization" problem which also underlies lateral dissimilation, namely it is perceptually hard-ish to localize *r* vs. *l* in the speech stream, and the "surface template" (if there is such a thing) is that the lateral should be first, thus liquid dissimilation tends to favor l...r. The idea behind the perceptual account is that a listener knows that there are liquids but isn't entirely sure what order they are, and they default the the order *l...r*.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if liquids and especially flaps and trills were the most likely sounds to move to a different location in a syllable. For one, they can often occur very freely. Since they are so sonorant, they occur adjacent to the syllable nucleus – so the extremes they can occur in are closer than of less sonorous consonants. And the articulation of flaps and trills can be very challenging in some environments – If you don't time the articulatory movement and your air stream right, the articulation can simply fail.

Comment: In Northern Italian and Occitan dialects, there are (sporadic, as in, heavily dialect-dependent) examples of liquid metathesis of the form *dormir* → *dromir*, or *comprar* → *crompar* (final <r> usually not pronounced, just sometimes present in the orthography).
In some Catalan dialects, while it's not metathesis but deletion, it's common to pronounce words like *aprendre* as *apendre*.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "surface template"?